# Updating Data-Attributes in Script using results from another script

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments, custom-data-attribute

I am creating an order form that uses Stripe Checkout.   Stripe has form with a script embedded in a page.  It looks like this:

```
.... 
<input type="text" id="emailInput"> .....
<input type="text" id="postCodeInput"> .....

<form action="myNextPage.php" method="POST" id="stripePay">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_EXAMPLEKEYCODE1234"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png"
    data-zipCode=""
    data-email=""
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

I want to update the data-email and the data-zipcode to mirror a text input on the same page.  I have been playing with something along these lines, but can't get it to work.

```
var val1=$('#emailInput').val;
$('#stripePay').data('email', val1);

var val2=$('#postCodeInput').val;
$('#stripePay').data('zipCode', val2);
```

This form will not be placed not on a publicly accessible page.

---

**Update - Workaround** 
I made a workaround using ajax to create the Stripe Checkout button dynamically using the data entered on this page.  I leave the stripe pay button off the form, and retrieve it when the post code and email data are entered.  I will use a combination of this approach and the Matthew's custom form in my final code.   For this example, I have not included any validation to make sure the input data is complete and as expected.

```
 .... 
<input type="text" id="emailInput"> .....
<input type="text" id="postCodeInput">


<div id="stripePayBtn">
    <!--ajax will place the stripe pay button here-->
</div>
<div>
    <button  id="nextBtn">
        Create Payment Button
    </button>
</div>
    ------

 // Script on this page:

 $("#nextBtn").click(function(){
     var zip = $("#postCodeInput").val();
     var email = $("#emailInput").val();
     var amount = $("#amount").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'stripePopulate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                zip : zip,
                email : email,
                amount : amount,
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success:function(data){
                $("#nextBtn").hide();
                $('#stripePayBtn').html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

Then, on the stripePopulate.php page

```
<?php

$zip=$_POST[zip];
$email=$_POST[email];
$amount=$_POST[amount];


echo'<form action="myNextPage.php" method="POST" id="stripePay">
  <script
       src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_EXAMPLEKEYCODE1234"
        data-amount="2000"
        data-name="Demo Site"
        data-description="2 widgets"
        data-image="/128x128.png"
       data-zipCode="'.$zip.'"
       data-amount="'.$amount.'"
       data-email="'.$email.'"
       data-locale="auto">
  </script>

</form>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Stripe configures itself when it first parses the html page, updating the values won't be reflected in Stripe's configuration. If you want to do something like that you'd need to use Stripe Checkout's custom integration which would allow you to specify the values when the user clicks the checkout button via javascript.

Comment: I was just starting to realize the same after removing the src link and viewing the console.log .   I will switch to the custom integration.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update ".stripe-button" with data-email and data-zipCode, try below:

```
var val1=$('#emailInput').val;
$('#stripePay .stripe-button').data('email', val1);

var val2=$('#postCodeInput').val;
$('#stripePay .stripe-button').data('zipCode', val2);
```

To check if has been added run:

```
console.log($('#stripePay .stripe-button').data('email'))
console.log($('#stripePay .stripe-button').data('zipCode'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the console.log hint - but this solution didn't populate the data attributes.   To check for typos, I populated other temporary input fields with the same data and saw the console.log correctly display that.